# Mongoid giving error while saving field with particular name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am using mongoid in rails app. rails 3.0.10 ruby 1.9.2p0

When I am trying to use field like "test", "link", "desc" etc.

say

```
Content.new(:test => 'ggg')

Content.new(:link => 'ggg')

Content.new(:desc => 'ggg')
```

Content is model which uses  "Mongoid::Document"

it gives following error. (this error is for field "test")

I think mongoid uses some library which contents above field names as functions which

might create problem. Is there any way to come around this problem.

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.0.10/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:155:in `test'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.0.10/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:155:in `attribute_will_change!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:102:in `block (2 levels) in write_attribute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:100:in `tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:100:in `block in write_attribute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:170:in `assigning'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:98:in `write_attribute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:95:in `process_attribute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:25:in `block in process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:23:in `each_pair'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb:23:in `process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/document.rb:128:in `block in initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/relations/builders.rb:47:in `building'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.2.4/lib/mongoid/document.rb:125:in `initialize'
    from (irb):1:in `new'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/harshal/simple-cms/branches/1.0/script/rails:6:in `require'
    from /home/harshal/simple-cms/branches/1.0/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you post your `Content` model too?

Comment: thanks Jeff Smith for your response. I  forgot to mention that the above field's is dynamically generated it's not predefined in model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest everything, ruby(1.9.3), rails(3.2.3), mongoid(2.4.7) I tried the following things:

Model with no set fields, all dynamic:

```
class Content
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

Rails console:

```
1.9.3p125 :011 > c = Content.new(:test => "test", :link=> "link", :desc => "desc")
 => #<Content _id: 4f7f49f5add3617fae000003, _type: nil, test: "test", link: "link", desc: "desc"> 
1.9.3p125 :012 > c.save
 => true 
1.9.3p125 :013 > Content.first
 => #<Content _id: 4f7f49f5add3617fae000003, _type: nil, test: "test", link: "link", desc: "desc"> 
1.9.3p125 :014 >
```

Model with all fields statically set:

```
class Content
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :test, :type => String
  field :link, :type => String
  field :desc, :type => String
end
```

Rails console again:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3p125 :001 > c = Content.new
 => #<Content _id: 4f7f4652add3617ec4000001, _type: nil, test: nil, link: nil, desc: nil> 
1.9.3p125 :002 > c.test = 'tyler'
 => "tyler" 
1.9.3p125 :003 > c.save
 => true 
1.9.3p125 :004 > Content.first
 => #<Content _id: 4f7f4652add3617ec4000001, _type: nil, test: "tyler", link: nil, desc: nil>
```

Comment: Hi Tyler Brock, the prob is my app is already using mongoid 2.2.4 and rails 3.0.10 and also having lots of other gems installed. Is there any way to continue with these gem rather upgrading to latest one. because it may possible that by upgrading these gem, the gem which depends on previous version may break.

Comment: I'm not sure if its a version issue specifically but you should be able to just upgrade mongoid to the latest version without issue. You can always go back by specifying a specific version in the Gemfile. What I would do is note what you have currently and then specify those versions again explicitly if something doesn't work.